# nullpointerexception in the entityManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa

i'm working on a project using Hibernate annotations and i'm having problem instanciating EntityManager .. when trying EntityManager.find() i'm getting a nullpointerexception 
i can't understand why ! any help please ?
here is some code

```
    Users.java
    package com.rimweb.users.persistance;

    // Generated 6 mars 2014 12:00:34 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.FetchType;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

    import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    /**
    * Users generated by hbm2java
    */
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users", catalog = "user")
    public class Users implements java.io.Serializable {

private Integer userid;
private Address address;
private String username;
private String password;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String email;

public Users() {
}

public Users(Address address, String username, String password,
        String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.address = address;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userid", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getUserid() {
    return this.userid;
}

public void setUserid(Integer userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "addressid")
public Address getAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Column(name = "username")
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Column(name = "password", length = 64)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Column(name = "firstname")
public String getFirstname() {
    return this.firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

@Column(name = "lastname")
public String getLastname() {
    return this.lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

@Column(name = "email")
public String getEmail() {
    return this.email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Users [userid=" + userid + ", username=" + username
            + ", password=" + password + ", firstname=" + firstname
            + ", lastname=" + lastname + ", email=" + email + "]";
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
 */
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((address == null) ? 0 : address.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((email == null) ? 0 : email.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstname == null) ? 0 : firstname.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((lastname == null) ? 0 : lastname.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((password == null) ? 0 : password.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((userid == null) ? 0 : userid.hashCode());
    result = prime * result
            + ((username == null) ? 0 : username.hashCode());
    return result;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see java.lang.Object#equals(java.lang.Object)
 */
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Users other = (Users) obj;
    if (address == null) {
        if (other.address != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!address.equals(other.address))
        return false;
    if (email == null) {
        if (other.email != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!email.equals(other.email))
        return false;
    if (firstname == null) {
        if (other.firstname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!firstname.equals(other.firstname))
        return false;
    if (lastname == null) {
        if (other.lastname != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!lastname.equals(other.lastname))
        return false;
    if (password == null) {
        if (other.password != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!password.equals(other.password))
        return false;
    if (userid == null) {
        if (other.userid != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!userid.equals(other.userid))
        return false;
    if (username == null) {
        if (other.username != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!username.equals(other.username))
        return false;
    return true;
}



}

    UsersHome.java:

    package com.rimweb.users.dao;

    // Generated 6 mars 2014 16:42:25 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
    import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
    import javax.persistence.Persistence;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
    import javax.persistence.PersistenceUnit;
    import javax.persistence.Query;

    import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
    import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

    import com.rimweb.users.persistance.Users; 

    /**
    * Home object for domain model class Users.
    * @see com.rimweb.users.dao.Users
    * @author Hibernate Tools
    */
    @Stateless
    public class UsersHome {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UsersHome.class);

@PersistenceContext(unitName="manager1")
//@PersistenceUnit
//EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory=       Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("manager1");
//private EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void persist(Users transientInstance) {
    log.debug("persisting Users instance");
    try {
        entityManager.persist(transientInstance);
        log.debug("persist successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("persist failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public void remove(Users persistentInstance) {
    log.debug("removing Users instance");
    try {
        entityManager.remove(persistentInstance);
        log.debug("remove successful");
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("remove failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public Users merge(Users detachedInstance) {
    log.debug("merging Users instance");
    try {
        Users result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
        log.debug("merge successful");
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("merge failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public Users findById(Integer id) {
    log.debug("getting Users instance with id: " + id);
    try {
        Users instance = entityManager.find(Users.class, id);
        log.debug("get successful");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}

public List<Users> findAll() {
    log.debug("getting all User instances");
    try {
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select u from Users u");
        List<Users> usersList = (List<Users>) query.getResultList();
        log.debug("findAll successful");
        return usersList;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("findAll failed", re);
        return new ArrayList<Users>();
    }
  }
    }


    MainTest.java

    package com.rimweb.users.dao;
    import java.math.BigDecimal;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.criterion.Order;
    import com.rimweb.users.persistance.Users;

    public class MainTest {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UsersHome dao = new UsersHome() ;

    Users us = dao.findById(new Integer(1));
    System.out.println("-Livre :"+us);

    //////////////////////////////////////////

    List<Users> list = dao.findAll(); 
    for(Users l : list)
    { System.out.println("##"+l);}


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you UserHome.java class there is Entity manager but it is null because you are creating the EntityManager just you have defined.

So creating the entity manager, please create the Util class...

for example HibernateUtil.java

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    static {
                try {
                     entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");

                } catch (Throwable ex) {

                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);

                  }
    }

public static EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
         return entityManagerFactory;
    }

}
```

And provide your persistence unit name to the following method instead of abc.

```
entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("abc");
```

Then create the entity manager in your every method with transaction.

for example...

```
public Users merge(Users detachedInstance) {
    log.debug("merging Users instance");
    try {
        em = HibernateUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
        Users result = entityManager.merge(detachedInstance);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
        log.debug("merge successful");
        return result;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        em.getTransaction().rollback();
        log.error("merge failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

This is enough for avoid the null pointer exception....

Comment: thank you bro .. i'm wondering may be ia have to deploy the entities on a JBoss server before i test them since i'm using EJB ??